# Best way to distributed massive ammounts on zip files

Tags: python, hadoop, distributed-computing, zeromq

I haven't much experience in distributed computing, but I would like to create a script within python to distribute unzip jobs centrally to x amount of servers, saving me from the hassle of routinely logging into multiple servers distributing unzip jobs on a file share.

What is the best tool for this sort of task, I wanted to play with hadoop in the future, but I don't know enough and am thinking this probably isn't the right tool for this job.  I have seen a few similar posts hinting at zeromq.   Just looking for advice on what tool would really be best suited for a job like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The I/O bound is usually going to be the problem, not CPU, when you are unzipping files. So logging on to multiple servers to unzip files on the same share is just going to plug up the network connection of the (file) server hosting that share.

On the other hand, if you are trying to unzip the **same** files on different servers, you don't need python at all. Check out the [`pssh`](http://www.theether.org/pssh/) command and its relatives.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I decided to make a fun project with celery.